# Extracting special word as a relation from parsed file in python

Tags: python

I have a file containing parsed data and looks like this:

```
defaultdict(<function DependencyGraph.__init__.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x11db74bf8>,
        {0: {'address': 0,
             'ctag': 'TOP',
             'deps': defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'ROOT': [6, 51]}),
             'feats': None,
             'head': None,
             'lemma': None,
             'rel': None,
             'tag': 'TOP',
             'word': None},
         1: {'address': 1,
             'ctag': 'Ne',
             'deps': defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'NPOSTMOD': [2]}),
             'feats': '_',
             'head': 6,
             'lemma': 'اشرف',
             'rel': 'SBJ',
             'tag': 'Ne',
             'word': 'اشرف'},
         2: {'address': 2,
             'ctag': 'AJ',
             'deps': defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {}),
             'feats': '_',
             'head': 1,
             'lemma': 'غنی',
             'rel': 'NPOSTMOD',
             'tag': 'AJ',
             'word': 'غنی'},
```

Now I want to extract relation from this data. I do not know how to get an element of this data. For example, I read this file and tried to see:

```
with open('parse.txt') as read_parsed_file:
parsed_file = read_parsed_file.read()
# print(parsed_file)
if "'rel': 'NVE'" in parsed_file:
    print("'word': ''")
```

I want from `index:1` if `'rel': 'SBJ'` and `'tag':'Ne',` then it has relation with `index:2,` but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to normalize your file data and then use json library to load your data

```
  import json

  with open('parse.txt') as f:
      data = json.load(f)

  for item in data:
    if "rel" in data[item]:
      print("in loop")
```

sample parse.txt

```
 {      "0": {"address": "0",
             "ctag": "TOP",
             "deps": "",
             "feats": "",
             "head": "",
             "lemma": "",
             "rel": "",
             "tag": "TOP",
             "word": ""},
         "1": {"address": "1",
             "ctag": "Ne",
             "deps": "",
             "feats": "_",
             "head": 6,
             "lemma": "اشرف",
             "rel": "SBJ",
             "tag": "Ne",
             "word": "اشرف"},
         "2": {"address": "2",
             "ctag": "AJ",
             "deps": "",
             "feats": "_",
             "head": 1,
             "lemma": "غنی",
             "rel": "NPOSTMOD",
             "tag": "AJ",
             "word": "غنی"}
   }
```

Comment: I normalized the data and it gives me this error:   `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

Comment: can you please share your normalized data

Comment: Is it important that all elements should be in double quotations?

Comment: Because the dataset is generated in real time, with the format that I have shared. What should I do with that?

Comment: yes for proper json parsing it needs to be in double quote & for your second  query , try converting your dataset (which is defaultdict) to dict first and then try.